# Starting and stopping SQL Server service by SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I'm trying to start and stop MS SQL Server 2014 (12.0.4487.0) by code in c# with SMO. I used this :
[Starting SQL Server via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837957/starting-sql-server-via-c-sharp?answertab=votes#tab-top)
and this :
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx
which are pretty much the same - one is in c# and other in VB.NET.

My code :

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi;
using System;

namespace TEST___SQL_Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SQLStart.StartSQLService();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static class SQLStart
    {
        public static void StartSQLService()
        {
            //Declare and create an instance of the ManagedComputer object that represents the WMI Provider services.
            ManagedComputer mc = default(ManagedComputer);
            mc = new ManagedComputer();

            //Iterate through each service registered with the WMI Provider.
            Service svc = default(Service);
            foreach (Service s in mc.Services)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
            }

            //Reference the Microsoft SQL Server service.
            svc = mc.Services[0]; // this is my MSSQLSERVER service

            //Stop the service if it is running and report on the status continuously until it has stopped.
            if (svc.ServiceState != ServiceState.Running)
            {
                //Start the service and report on the status continuously until it has started.
                svc.Start();
                while (!(string.Format("{0}", svc.ServiceState) == "Running"))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", svc.ServiceState));
                    svc.Refresh();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} service state is {1}", svc.Name, svc.ServiceState));

                svc.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} service state is {1}", svc.Name, svc.ServiceState));
                while (!(string.Format("{0}", svc.ServiceState) == "Stopped"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", svc.ServiceState));
                    svc.Refresh();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} service state is {1}", svc.Name, svc.ServiceState));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SQL Server service is not running.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get it but when I do `svc.Start();` in my code to start up SQL Server service (which is intentionally and initially stopped) nothing is happening. I keep receiving state that service is stopped and it seems from my perspective that nothing is happening.

Am I missing something or this SMO doesn't work at all ? 
Thanks

Comment: I guess you are stopping another service, because you are stopping the first one, how did you guarantee that it's the SQL Server service?

Comment: I know that it's my SQL Server Service because I listed all services while debugging. It's sql server service 100%. It doesn't matter how do I create reference to this service - by index or by name. I can do that `svc = mc.Services["MSSQL$MYINSTANCE"]` and problem stays the same.

Comment: It would make a big difference, you might reference another one, your comment is not valid

Comment: Have you tried a ServiceController ?